# Smooth sensitivity for high-dimensional problems

Tags: pr.probability

Smooth sensitivity comes from the following paper:

https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1250790.1250803?casa_token=YKSULDNu3Z8AAAAA:WADiq2I4UfObJ54o0PWi8VB_Dmo16tUcsH0_v6foq4efD6fB1eR_hpP4ceVHTQyCNLrMMkt2935gquE

Now I need the parameter $(\alpha, \beta)$ for high dimensional problems. I found example 3 in the paper, which states that $\beta=\Omega(\epsilon/\sqrt{d}\ln(1/\delta))$ for Laplace distribution and $\beta=\Omega(\epsilon/\sqrt{d\ln(1/\delta)})$ for Gaussian distribution.

Here $\alpha$ is fixed, but there is only an asymptotic lower bound on $\beta$, i.e. $\beta=\Omega(...)$. Are there some precise (numerical) bounds on $\beta$ in high dimensionality?